# Which algorithm is used to calculate checksum?

Tags: protocols, checksum, serial-communication

I am trying to decipher the protocol used for RS485 communication between several HVAC controllers. I was able to identify single messages as you can see in the list below.

```
00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010303400012A7
2001030A400012010104FFFFFFFF7E

00010303400016A3
200103094000160C0C010400441C

000103074100000024A003ED
2001030A4100000024A0030895BA73

0001032A90020030000200310700013000020131070002300002023107060330000203310700043000FF053000FF1F
2001030290004A

00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010302D10227
20010312D140200100002101000022010000230100002F

00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010302D20226
20010302D240C8

00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010302D10227
20010312D140200100002101000022010000230100002F

00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010302D20226
20010302D240C8

00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010302D20226
20010302D240C8

00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010302D20226
20010302D240C8

00020003400012A9
00030103400012A7

00010302D20226
20010302D240C8
```

Each line contains one complete message in hex format. I think the last byte (last two hex characters) is the checksum of the previous data, but that is only a guess of me.

Which algorithm is used to calculate this checksum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now discovered the algorithm. Its only summing up data and building some kind of 2s complement. Here is an example:

```
data: 0x20010312D14020010000210100002201000023010000

binary sum: 1 1101 0001 (0x1D1)
last byte:    1101 1110 (0xD1)
invert:       0010 1110 (0x2E)
add 1:        0010 1111 (0x2F)
use only last byte of calculated CS

CS: 0x2F
```